# Find the limit of the sequence defined by $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}^*,u_n = \frac{2n(2n-1)}{4n^2+1} u_{n-1}$ and $u_0 =1$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

Let $(u_n)$ be the sequence defined by $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}^*,u_n = \frac{2n(2n-1)}{4n^2+1} u_{n-1}$ and $u_0 =1$. I would like to find another way to find the limit of $(u_n)$.

---

What I have done:

We can see that $(u_n)$ is a strictly positive decreasing sequence so it converges, and by induction we can show that :

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, u_n = \displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{2k(2k-1)}{4k^2+1}$$

And I end up with:

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, u_n = \displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{2k(2k-1)}{4k^2+1} \leq \prod_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{2k(2k-1)}{4k^2} = \prod_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{2k-1}{2k} $$

I managed to show that:

$$ \prod_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{2k-1}{2k}  = \dfrac{(2n)!}{(2^nn!)^2} \stackrel{\text{stirling}}{\sim} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n \pi}} $$

Therefore $\displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{2k-1}{2k} \underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$ and by the squeeze theorem we deduce that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }u_n=0 $.

Do you see another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would proceed as follows: you already know that $u_n$ converges to a non negative limit.
Also you can write $$u_n = \prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k(2k-1)}{4k^2+1} = \prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{2k+1}{4k^2+1}\right)$$
By a well-known theorem this product is divergent, since $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2k+1}{4k^2+1}$ is divergent. Moreover, as $u_n$ converges being monotone decreasing and bounded below, it follows that this product must diverge to $0$, which is your limit.

This might be useful:
[Equivalence of convergence of a series and convergence of an infinite product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2027618/equivalence-of-convergence-of-a-series-and-convergence-of-an-infinite-product)
Even though this link refers to positive $a_n$'s, it's still valid when all the $a_n$'s are negative.

Comment: Does your well-known theorem has a name? Could you provide more details? Well I disagree, if $a_n = -1$ for all $n$ then the result is false. Thank you for the effort but your answer is not clear enough for me.

Comment: When $a_n = -1$ for all $n$ the product is not convergent in the product sense. See here for more details for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#:~:text=The%20product%20is%20said%20to,product%20is%20said%20to%20diverge.&text=If%20the%20product%20converges%2C%20then,is%20in%20general%20not%20true.

Comment: A necessary condition for the convergence of any product $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1+a_k)$ is certainly $a_k \to 0$ as $k \to +\infty$

Comment: Ok thank you for the link, I am not familiar with convergence of infinite product.

Comment: You should learn about them! There's a very nice theory which relates them to infinite  series.

Comment: I realized afterwards that I did not need any help. But thank you for introducing me this notion of infinite product.